# Communication between siblings components Vue.js to change the view of card only when inserting it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

i have a problem when i click on insert text button on component B it will add text card which is component A.. when inserting card i need textarea, and save button to be show then after click on save textarea must be hidden that's done but the problem is when reload the page the text area and save button become shown again..
note A, B are siblings

//Component A

```
<template>
  <div class="answer-text-container answer-inner-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p class="answer-type">{{ text.type }}</p>
      <p v-show="!this.show" class="answer-text">{{ text.body }}</p>

      <textarea v-model="text.body" v-show="this.show" rows="3" class="edit-text-area border rounded" placeholder="Enter the text here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container" v-show="!this.show">
      <button type="button" @click="editText" class="btn btn-primary edit-text-btn">
        <i v-bind:class="[editTextString]"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" @click="$emit('delete')" class="btn btn-danger edit-text-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="editText" class="btn btn-success rounded" v-show="this.show">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: 0,
      editTextString: "far fa-edit"
    };
  },
  props: ["text"],
  methods: {
    editText() {
      this.show = !this.show;
      console.log(this.text);
    },
    removeTextComp() {}
  }
};
```

//component B

```
<template>
  <div class="toolbar-container mb-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 p-0 text-center">
      <div class="row mx-0">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-0 d-inline-block toolbar-sub-container">
          <a @click="insertText" href="#">
            <p>Insert Text</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    insertText() {
      this.$parent.insertTextComp();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`show:0` is entry value. When you reload page, this value too reload. So if you wanna have an actual value of `show` after reloading use localStorage or vuex store.  And one more, I mean be better if your `show` value will be boolean.

Comment: thanks Dima, but i'm new with Vue.js so can you help me how to use localStorage in this case

Comment: https://javascript.info/localstorage  read this, and find in google 'vue lifecycle hooks'. Then use 'mounted' hook to apply current show value from storage. And in watcher add new show value to localStorage. That what i do, but i dont know or it best way.

Comment: @AsmaaM.Elmohamady did i answer for your questions?